# paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk @"^1.0" issue when completing purchase (not triggering return_url)

Tags: laravel, paypal, sdk

I'm having an issue while trying to finalize the purchase on my paypal checkout link, everything step works well, until I'm following the checkout redirect URL, when clicking the "complete purchase" button nothing happens, no more api requests are triggered in paypal dashboard besides the first one, and it simply refreshes the page

Below is my Order body code, which works as intended

```
$order->body = [
            'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
            'purchase_units' => [
                [
                    'description' => $payment->payableDescription(),
                    'amount' => [
                        'currency_code' => "USD",
                        'value' => round($payment->payableValue(), 2)
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            'payer' => [
                'email_address' => $user->email,
            ],
            'application_context' => [
                'shipping_preference' => 'NO_SHIPPING',
                'user_action' => 'PAY_NOW'
            ],
            'redirect_urls' => [
                'cancel_url' => route('web.payment.cancel', $payment->payableIdentifier()),
                'return_url' => route('web.payment.approve', $payment->payableIdentifier()),
            ]
        ];
```

my return and cancel URLs call into another controller which finalize the payment in the backend, but no matter what link is being called, paypal doesn't trigger the event, I tried manually calling the methods, they work as expected.
Feel free to ask for more info.
Any help is appreciated

tried almost everything besides changing the SDK or trying to upgrade the package itselt, all my needs are for paypal to call into the return_url route

Answer (score 0):

- That @paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk as well as all other and older REST SDKs are deprecated, not supported, and should not be used for any new integrations. Instead implement your own HTTPS functions forr first getting an access_token and then doing the call. See the REST API documentation, beginning with [authentication](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/authentication/) and then the [Orders API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create).
- Redirect integrations are an old integration pattern, and should also not be used. See [the standard checkout integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/). The JS will open a window as needed or display inline forms on your site, and fetch from two routes on your server (one to create the order, the other to capture it after approval).

Comment: I understand the issue of building a system with a depreciated package, however it was something that fulfilled my needs exactly as was required. However I found a fix, after an update to Paypal API, there was issued a change into the main branch, the array key 'redirect_urls' was refactored and now only works when the 'cancel_url' and 'return_url' are being read within 'application_context' so it should go as follows (for my case):

Comment: 'application_context' => [
                'shipping_preference' => 'NO_SHIPPING',
                'user_action' => 'PAY_NOW'
                'cancel_url' => route('web.payment.cancel', $payment->payableIdentifier()),
                'return_url' => route('web.payment.approve', $payment->payableIdentifier()),
            ],

Comment: In addition to the paypal-checkout-sdk itself being deprecated, the application_context object is also a deprecated API parameter that should not be used. See the current API reference for what you should be using for current integrations. Although this only applies to a redirect flow, if using the JS SDK for approval (which you should), neither the deprecated application_object nor its current replacement are needed.